# condicional sobre web.config

Tags: vb.net, condiciones, web.config

buenas tardes en un proyecto tengo una key en web.config dependiendo del estado true o false debe habilitar un campo en mi formulario entre un dropdawnlist y un boton esto es lo que tengo:
web.config.

```
<add key="habilitar_boton" value="true"/>
```

en el proyecto:

```
    Private ReadOnly Property _HabilitarAcompanantes() As Boolean
    Get
        Dim bHabilitarAcompanantes As Boolean = True
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("habilitar_multiseleccion_acompanante_gestion")) Then
            bHabilitarAcompanantes = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("habilitar_multiseleccion_acompanante_gestion"))
        End If

        Return bHabilitarAcompanantes
    End Get
End Property
```

y el condicional

```
If _HabilitarAcompanantes = True Then
            Me.divUnicoAcompanante.Visible = Me._HabilitarAcompanantes
        Else
            If _HabilitarAcompanantes = False Then
                Me.divUnicoAcompanante.Visible = False And Me.btnMultiAcompanantes.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
```

el problema es que cuando dejo la key a true me muestra los dos campos no me oculta el dropdawnlist

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿El nombre de la key es `habilitar_multiseleccion_acompanante_gestion` o `habilitar_boton`? Si te das cuenta en tu código es diferente.

Comment: Y eso es exactamente lo que dice tu codigo. cuando es true, esta todo visible. Si no es lo que querias hacer, explica mejor la logica y te ayudamos..

Comment: disculpa es añadir boton

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que cuando este a true solo muestre el boton cuando este a false se muestre el dropdawnlist